# In Ansible, how do I iterate over a list of key/value pairs?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Say I have a defaults/main.yml file that has

```
---
my_vars:
- var1: value1
- var2: value2
```

How can I write my task to output my variables?

```
- debug: msg="The value of {{item.key}} is {{ item.value }}"
  with_items:
  - "What to put here???"
```

Comment: just set the vars as a dict and use "with_dict" instead https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be asking X but stating Y in your example. What I mean is that a list of key/value pairs that can be iterated through would look like this:

```
my_vars:
- var1: value1
  var2: value2
```

Or even like this:

```
my_vars:
  var1: value1
  var2: value2
```

To deal with your list of dicts, here's an example. I've added a variable to show how the dict is 'clumped'.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    my_var:
    - var1: value1
      varX: valueY
    - var2: value2
  tasks:
  - debug: var=item
    with_items: "{{my_var}}"
  - debug: var=item.var1
    when: "'var1' in item"
    with_items: "{{my_var}}"
```

output:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'varX': 'valueY', 'var1': 'value1'}) => {
    "item": {
        "var1": "value1",
        "varX": "valueY"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'var2': 'value2'}) => {
    "item": {
        "var2": "value2"
    }
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'varX': 'valueY', 'var1': 'value1'}) => {
    "item": {
        "var1": "value1",
        "varX": "valueY"
    },
    "item.var1": "value1"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'var2': 'value2'})
```

Again, you can see the 'clumping', var1 and varX show in the same iteration. Ansible doesn't deal with deep nesting well. A case where Ansible can handle lists of dicts is when they are referring to similar things:

```
my_vars:
- name: bob
  legs: 4
  type: cow
- name: alice
  legs: 2
  type: bird
```

You can then iterate through that in two ways- either with_items or with_subelements.

If you truly have hetrogenous keys in lists and want to iterate through them one at a time, you would have to use nested includes (yuck). You can also build a filter. I've never done the former and have only done the latter once.

Comment: How is your first example different in terminology from the one OP posted? In either case it's a list of dictionaries, not a "list of list of dicts". In your case the list has a single element, in his - two elements. OP uses correct wording imho.

Comment: And in the second example you defined a collection of key-value pairs, otherwise known as a dictionary. Simplifying - you defined a dictionary.

Comment: right, the second is a dictionary. I removed the "list of lists" and added some explanation about lists with key names that don't match.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't make sense of it. You basically state the task is impossible, right?

Comment: We're missing a lot from the OP about what they are *actually* doing.

Comment: No, we are not. He wants two lines printed given the data in the question: `The value of var1 is value1` and `The value of var2 is value2`.

Comment: if so, it's a simple `with_items` then. I think there's a lot missing.

Comment: No, it's not "simple `with_items`" and precisely that's why OP asked a question.